# how to get the query used for creating a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table

I'm new to Oracle and learning about tables using the HR db, i wanted to ask does there exist any command to view the query used to create the predefined tables? (I am not talking about the Desc/ribe command).
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `getddl()` function from [the `dbms_metadata` package](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_METADATA.html#GUID-A4683EEE-6F54-4081-B7BF-1496096675FA).

As an example, the following query gives you the DDL for table `mytable` in schema `HR`:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','MYTABLE','HR') from dual;
```

If you want the information for all tables in the `HR` schema at once, you can do:

```
select table_name, dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', table_name, owner) 
from all_tables 
where owner = 'HR';
```

Comment: @SalvadoreRina: please elaborate. Are you getting errors?

Comment: invalid input value TABLES for parameter OBJECT_TYPE in function GET_DDL, this is the error

Comment: @SalvadoreRina: the first argument it is `'TABLE'`, not `'TABLES'`.

Comment: yes but the table section is not found if i type this command, in my hr schema it is named Tables

Comment: @SalvadoreRina: what is the name of the table whose DDL you want to see?

Comment: the employee department etc table, i wanna see the query that was used for creating them

Comment: @SalvadoreRina: ok, so: `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','EMPLOYEE','HR') from dual;`

Answer (score 1):

There is a client-side command, if you're using SQLcl or SQL Developer

`ddl *table_name`*

[image]

I talk more about it [here](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2016/05/configuring-your-generated-ddl-in-sql-developer-and-sqlcl/)